# Angular inline Filter "controller side"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a selection of categories  that are returned after selection  correctly
to a  Html view by {{cat}}    would display Comics if Comics was selected from a list

```
$scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
       console.log(newCategory);
        $scope.cat = newCategory;
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
        $scope.selectedPage = 1;
    }
```

However I want to filter array of objects by this category controller side 
not by the usual inline filters in the view which I'm well aware of

If I manually add the Category in the example below Comics

```
$scope.edition_products = $filter('filter')
 ( $scope.filteredItems, {approved: true, category: "Comics"});
```

Only category Comics that are approved true are returned   so the filter works

But How do I make it dynamic by injecting inline the $scope.cat

e.g.

```
$scope.edition_products = $filter('filter')
( $scope.filteredItems, {approved: true, [$scope.cat]}
```

note  this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Filter in controller doesn't automatically trigger. You have to run the filter each time you select the category, so in your `selectCategory` function you have to re-run the filter

Such as

```
$scope.selectCategory = function (newCategory) {
   console.log(newCategory);
   $scope.cat = newCategory;
   selectedCategory = newCategory;
   $scope.selectedPage = 1;
   $scope.edition_products = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredItems {approved: true, category: $scope.cat});
}
```

Doing so will filter the data each time you change the category.